# Add list of values to end of each line in selection

Tags: notepad++

Looking for a way to add a list of values to the end of the line for a selection.

Here is an example:

I have a group of text such as:

> update stores set x = 
>   update stores set x = 
>   update stores set x =

I have a list of values such as:

> 1168 
>   7345 
>   3358

I would like to paste in the values so that the resulting text would be:

> update stores set x = 1168 
>   update stores set x = 7345 
>   update stores set x = 3358

Thinking there must be a way in `Notepad+`+ or related plugin that would allow this.

Also, in this case, I cannot start with the list of values and then prepend the text using the `Notepad++` find/replace `regex` using `^`.  This is because I am already doing this with a different set of unique values.  I'm trying to paste a separate set of values to the end of the lines that already have unique values within the lines.

Comment: One workaround I will use for now is to use excel with multiple columns.  Separate columns for the text portions and separate for the data sections.  I then paste this into the text file.  Would be nice though to be able to do it within the text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible even if both sets of text are not fixed:

1. In your 1st file, hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> + select with your mouse ALL your text.
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy.
3. Then go to the 2nd file and leave the cursor flickering at the very beginning of your file.
4. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste.

For example:

File A:

```
set1 = 
set2 = 
set33 =
```

File B:

```
123
4560
789
```

Result:

```
set1 = 123
set2 = 4560
set33 = 789
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to edit in multiple lines simulatenously ("column mode").

So copy one string of `update stores set x =`, then place the caret at the start of you values:

```
[caret here]1168 
7345 
3358
```

Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and press arrow down or page down to select the entire column

```
[caret here]1168 
[caret here]7345 
[caret here]3358
```

And paste!

edit: if you need to paste at the end of a string instead, the procedure is completely analogous. Just place the caret in whichever column you need to paste.

Comment: Yes, that option would work in the simple example case I used with a single list of values that you are starting with.  In this case though I'm working with two sets of changing data values that will need to be in each line.  So the trick is getting both sets of data values in each line with the static text in between.  Imagine the example lines being "update Astores set x = " ... "update Bstores set x = ".  Only way I see to do this is with excel currently.